# Getting a form to send an selected option to email

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

Hi i have been trying for a good 2 hours to get this dropdown menu to get the selected result to go to email through post method im new to php and i think i could just do with abit of guidance ill post html php js code below.i have tried many ways this isnt my only edit ive literally tried everything i just need a little help

html

```
    <div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="form-group mt-2">
<div class="dropdown" >
    <select name="vehicles" id="vehicles" class="ddstyle">
    <option value="motor" selected>Motorcycle</option>
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Small">Small Van</option>
    <option value="Opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="Midi">Midi Van</option>
    <option value="SWB">SWB up to 2.4m</option>
    <option value="MWB3">MWB up to 3m</option>
    <option value="LWB4">LWB up to 4m</option>
    <option value="XLWB4">XLWB 4m+</option>
    <option value="Luton">Luton</option>
    <option value="T5">7.5T</option>
  </select>     
</div>
</div>                          
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name      = $_POST['name'];
$email     = $_POST['email'];
$comments  = $_POST['comments'];
$dod       = $_POST['dod'];
$yourname  = $_POST['yourname'];
$tel       = $_POST['tel'];
$caddy     = $_POST['caddy'];
$cpost     = $_POST['cpost'];
$daddy     = $_POST['daddy'];
$dpost     = $_POST['dpost'];
$dofd      = $_POST['dofd'];
$Car       = $_POST['Car'];
$Small     = $_POST['Small'];
$Opel      = $_POST['Opel'];
$Midi      = $_POST['Midi'];
$MWB       = $_POST['MWB'];
$MWB3      = $_POST['MWB3'];
$LWB4      = $_POST['LWB4'];
$XLWB4     = $_POST['XLWB4'];
$Luton     = $_POST['Luton'];
$T5        = $_POST['T5'];
//*$vehicles  = $_POST['$vehicles'];**/

 if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    if(isset($_POST['vehicles'])){
        $value = $_POST['vehicles'];
        $ddme = $_POST['value'];
    }
 }
if(isset($_POST['vehicles']) && $_POST['vehicles']=='motor') echo $value;
    

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_msg">You must enter your company name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_msg">Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_msg">You have entered an invalid e-mail address. Please try again.</div>';
    exit();

}

if(trim($dod) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_msg">Please enter your collection date.</div>';
    exit();
}
if(trim($dofd) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_msg">Please enter your drop off deadline.</div>';
    exit();
}
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}

   
// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "example@example.net";
$address = "admin@ready2gologistics.co.uk";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = '  ' . $name . ' has a possible job!';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "$name wants a quote details are listed below." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = 
"
Company: $name
Name of Person: $yourname
Contacts email: $email
Contacts Telephone Number: $tel

Desired Collection Date: $dod
Drop Off Deadline: $dofd

Collection Address: $caddy
Collection Post Code: $cpost

Destination Address: $daddy
Destination Post Code: $dpost 

Addtional Information: $comments

test: $value
" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_msg'>";
    echo "<h3>Email Sent Successfully.</h3>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your quote has been submitted to us. To see how we use your information check out our <a href='PrivacyPolicy.html".$link_address."'>Privacy Policy</a></p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
    ?>
```

JavaScript

```
//Contact
$('#working_form').submit(function() {

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $("#message").slideUp(750, function() {
        $('#message').hide();

        $('#submit')
            .before('<img src="" class="gif_loader" />')
            .attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $.post(action, {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                comments: $('#comments').val(),
                dod: $('#dod').val(),
                dofd: $('#dofd').val(),
                yourname: $('#yourname').val(),
                cpost: $('#cpost').val(),
                caddy: $('#caddy').val(),
                tel: $('#tel').val(),
                daddy: $('#daddy').val(),
                dpost: $('#dpost').val(),
                vehicles: $('#vehicles').val(),
                value: $('#value').val(),
            
            },
            function(data) {
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#cform img.gif_loader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $(this).remove()
                });
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if (data.match('success') != null) $('#cform').slideUp('slow');
            }
        );

    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: You are not passing `send` in `$.post` call, so `isset($_POST['send']` will never satisfy

Comment: Please could you show me what you mean I don’t understand

Answer (score 0):

In `$.post` request pass `send` value

```
$.post(action, {
    ...other data
    value: $('#value').val(),
    send: $('#send').val(),
}
```

Because your `$value` vehicle data is depended on `if(isset($_POST['send']))` check

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    if(isset($_POST['vehicles'])){
        $value = $_POST['vehicles'];
        $ddme = $_POST['value'];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Okay guys so ive claimed the var in js

       vehicles: $('#vehicles').val(),
       value: $('#value').val(),
       send: $('#send').val(),

this is my php

if(isset($_POST['vehicles']) && $_POST['vehicles']=='motor') echo $value;
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    if(isset($_POST['vehicles'])){
        $value = $_POST['vehicles'];
        $ddme = $_POST['value'];
    }
 }

then where i want the option value to show in the email i am calling $value is this correct

Comment: Your `$value` will have some content only when `$vehicle` value equals `motor`, In email template you are setting it as `test: $value`, It seems alright